# Adding REST route to an existing Jetty endpoint in Camel at runtime

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have been inventing a way how to work around the problem of adding consumers to a jetty endpoint (it does not allow multiple consumers). The way we do it in our company is to build our own router and a broadcasting endpoint which consumes from jetty and routes requests to underlying "subscriptions". Only one of them will eventually process the request. It kind of works but it's not completely ok, since recently when updating to latest Camel we have found our custom built component to leak memory and in general I consider using built-in functionality over custom hacks.

I started investigating the Camel REST API and found it very nice and pretty much replacing our home-grown component apart from one thing - you cannot re-configure it at runtime - you have to stop the context basically for this to work. Below I include my unit test with a happy path and the path that fails. Frankly I think is a bug, but if there is a legitimate way to achieve what I want, I'd like to hear sound advice:

```
package com.anydoby.camel;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Test tries to add/remove routes at runtime.
 */
public class RoutesTest {

  private DefaultCamelContext ctx;

  @Before
  public void pre() throws Exception {
    ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
    new RouteBuilder(ctx) {

      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration("jetty").host("localhost").port(8080);

        rest("/")

            .get("/issues/{isin}").route().id("issues")
            .process(e -> e.getOut().setBody("Here's your issue " + e.getIn().getHeader("isin"))).endRest()

            .get("/listings").route().id("listings").process(e -> e.getOut().setBody("some listings"));
      }
    }.addRoutesToCamelContext(ctx);
    ctx.start();
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws IOException {
    {
      InputStream stream = new URL("http://localhost:8080/issues/35").openStream();
      assertEquals("Here's your issue 35", IOUtils.toString(stream));
    }
    {
      InputStream stream = new URL("http://localhost:8080/listings").openStream();
      assertEquals("some listings", IOUtils.toString(stream));
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void disableRoute() throws Exception {
    ctx.stopRoute("issues");
    ctx.removeRoute("issues");

    try (InputStream stream = new URL("http://localhost:8080/issues/35").openStream()) {
      fail();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    new RouteBuilder(ctx) {

      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        rest().get("/issues/{isin}/{sedol}").route().id("issues")
            .process(e -> e.getOut()
                .setBody("Here's your issue " + e.getIn().getHeader("isin") + ":" + e.getIn().getHeader("sedol")))
            .endRest();
      }
    }.addRoutesToCamelContext(ctx);

    {
      InputStream stream = new URL("http://localhost:8080/issues/35/65").openStream();
      assertEquals("Here's your issue 35:65", IOUtils.toString(stream));
    }
  }

}
```

The disableRoute() test fails since I cannot add another consumer to an existing endpoint.

So my question is - "is there a way to add a new URL mapping to a restful camel-jetty endpoint"? If you do it during first configuration it works fine, but when later you want to reconfigure one of the routes the error is:

> org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: jetty:http://localhost:8080/issues/%7Bisin%7D/%7Bsedol%7D?httpMethodRestrict=GET

Comment: I've been debugging camel after asking this question and I am now more convinced that this is a bug. Filed a ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10537